# Rescaffold migration in Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

In EF .Net a migration can be rescaffolded with the following:

```
Add-Migration <migration_name> -force
```

Can i force rescaffold same migration in Entity Framework Core?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is [no such option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell).

But you may remove it and create again:

```
Remove-Migration
Add-Migration <migration_name>
```

Comment: That's outrageous :) EF 6 has this :)

Comment: I share this outrage ;)

Comment: Grrrrrrrrrrrrrr